# Trying to find manuals for an obsolete instrument

Tags: discussion

Is a question asking if anyone knows where to find manuals for an obsolete instrument off topic?

The company that made the instrument was sold to Thermo Fisher Scientific, but Thermo Fisher does not have the manuals. I don't know where else to go.

Comment: IMO it would be better to ask in chat.

Comment: I am not sure if chat would help, but the question would probably be received as off-topic. But that also might depend on the instrument you want to know more about. You might get lucky at academia.se, when you ask something along the lines of "What to do when you need a manual, but the company does not exist any more?" And include your research, but I would not be too sure about it, that either SE can actually help :(

Comment: So, um, _what is the instrument_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Since there were somewhat mixed responses, I decided to post my question. Here it is. http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/30866/4813

Comment: @Cohen_the_Librarian: Wow, I totally didn't even spot that this post is on _meta_! :)

Answer (score 5):

*I would not close the question as off-topic.*

*Thermo Fisher* and its predecessor(s) bought a lot of companies, such as *Carlo Erba* (gas chromatography), Nicolet (IR spectroscopy), etc.

Do you know some older staff members who worked with the instrument? These might know (former) local technical representatives of the company that manufactured the instrument.

If you're looking for a description of proprietary binary data formats, prepare to start your favourite hex editor instead! The formats were largely undocumented. On the other hand, if you only have to process old data stored as JCAMP-DX, you're easy off!

Comment: Ahhhhh - memories of the days spent deciphering the data format from a Nicolet FTIR spectrometer that ran on Nicolet's proprietary 24-bit operating system with 24-bit integers. At least it had the decency to write files to DOS formatted disks in addition to its own weird format.